# How to add values to nested state array in reducer payload?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, react-state

I'm trying to *add* values from a response into my Redux state in the reducer. I have a state object that looks like this:

```
state: {
  currentUser: {
    loggedIn: boolean,
    follows: [string array],
    following: [string array],
    uid: string
  }
}
```

There are others, but this shows the shape that I need to add to. When a `follow` is added from a response, I need to add it to the `following` array. When I try to access it, it says it 'could possibly be null.' Is there something I need to be doing? I'm specifically looking at ADD_FOLLOW action.

```
import actions from '../actions/userActions'

const initialState = {
  loggedIn: false,
  currentUser: null
}

export const userReducer = (state: any = initialState, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // User logic will go here
    case actions.LOG_IN: {
      console.log('user logged in! Action obj: ', action)
      sessionStorage.setItem('user_object', JSON.stringify(action.payload))
      return {
        ...state,
        loggedIn: true,
        currentUser: {
          ...action.payload,
          uid: action.payload._id
        }
      }
    }

    case actions.LOG_OUT: {
      sessionStorage.clear()
      return initialState
    }

    case actions.REAUTH: {
      return state
    }

    case actions.UPDATE_INFO: {
      console.log('payload for update user: ', action.payload)
      return {
        ...state,
        currentUser: {
          ...action.payload
        }
      }
    }

    case actions.ADD_FOLLOW: {
      return {
        ...state,
        currentUser: {
          follows: [
            ...state.currentUser.follows || [],
            action.payload.resource_id
          ]
        }
      }
    }

    default: {
      return state
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `currentUser` could be null. Maybe you want `state.currentUser?.follows || []`?

Comment: It still shows errors. I'm assuming because my initial state is null (before they log in) but they can't add a follow until they're logged in. How would I set it to not complain? Even with the optional chain it says is *could* be null.

Comment: What's the exact error and on what line? You should probably support adding a follow when they're not logged in *just in case* (e.g. if `ADD_FOLLOW` is called by sockets, they might not be logged in on the page but still receive that socket message).

Comment: It's not. The action (and response) is dependent on currentUser being a value. You can't add a follow without it. I thought adding a bang would fix it but it doesn't either.

Comment: What's the exact error and on what line?

Comment: @JoelHager You are not copying currentUser in `ADD_FOLLOW`: `currentUser: { ...state.currentUser, follows: `